# How to create a jupyter extension based on an existing react component

Tags: reactjs, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a react component which does some complex, interactive visualization, including downloading data. 
I would like this to be available from jupyter notebook and/or jupyterlab.

I'm almost certain this requires writing an extension, and the process for creating extensions seems significantly different for jupyter notebook and jupyterlab.

I've looked up several existing extensions, and found jupyter-react-js, which seems abandoned. jupyterlab claims better integration with react, in particular https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer/virtualdom.html showing how to wrap react components. It's not clear at all though where code such as this would go, and how it would be available in a python notebook.

There are a number of extensions in the jupyterlab github, but documentation is sparse, and none of them do something similar enough. Most things are based on ipywidgets, or mime-type extensions.

How can I get these things to cooperate nicely?

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: Not really, in the end the versioning conflicts were too severe.